# I want to insert the data of second query if first query have inserted its data

Tags: php, mysqli

i am trying to insert a data. But i am getting an error and i can't solve it any help will be really appreciated

> Error: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, boolean given

```
$insert_qryy = mysqli_query($con,"Insert into user_register(name,email,phone,cphone,address,city,country,dob)
values('".$name."','".$email."','".$phone."','".$cphone."','".$address."','".$cityr."','".$country."','".$dob."')")or die(mysqli_error());

if ($insert_qryy->num_rows==0)
{   
    echo "Error";
}
else
{      
    $handler = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `addproperty`(`purpose`, `property_type`, `city`, `title`, `description`,         
`property_price`, `land_area`, `expires_after`, `property_img`) VALUES('".$purpose."','".$type."','".$city."','".$title."','".$desc."','".$price."',
'".$landarea."','".$expiry."','".$im."')") or die (mysqli_error());
}
```

it is entering the $insert_qryy data but the second statement is not working If statement is getting false i hope I'll get my solution here

Comment: @adelowo its not the issue .. and I've tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: Problem is `Insert` query return a boolen value true or false, based on query executed or not. So you can not use it in `mysqli_num_rows()`. try :-`if ($insert_qryy)
{  `

Comment: Learn Some Coding buddy,

Comment: Insert query does not return rows

Comment: Get last insert id u can not numrows or use effected rows

Comment: @Anant its not helpful

Comment: @SherKhan if you are a good coder so bro  find me a solution it will be really apreciated..

Comment: Explain what you wanna acheive and then we can help coz your current code is wrong

Comment: @Anant Its showing error that i've did echo its mean its showing that its working

Comment: @SherKhan actually its showing me the error that i have did echo its mean that my code ain't wrong

Comment: You want to check whether query was successful or want to check how many rows got inserted?

Comment: No i want to insert the data of second query if first query have inserted its data

Comment: So you just want to check whether first query was successful or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said - **`No i want to insert the data of second query if first query have inserted its data`**.check this once:-

```
$insert_qryy = mysqli_query($con,"Insert into user_register(name,email,phone,cphone,address,city,country,dob) values('".$name."','".$email."','".$phone."','".$cphone."','".$address."','".$cityr."','".$country."','".$dob."')")or die(mysqli_error($con));

if ($insert_qryy)
{   
  $handler = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `addproperty`( `purpose`, `property_type`, `city`, `title`, `description`,`property_price`, `land_area`, `expires_after`, `property_img`) VALUES  ('".$purpose."','".$type."','".$city."','".$title."','".$desc."','".$price."','".$landarea."','".$expiry."','".$im."')") or die (mysqli_error($con));
} else{
   echo "First Insert not executed properly";
}
```

Note:- Problem is `Insert` query return a boolen value true or false, based on query executed or not. So you can not use it directly in `mysqli_num_rows()`, because it ask for a `result-set object` as parameter not a `boolean` value.

Comment: Yes this is the third solution... Bro

Comment: @devpro i didn't get you.

Comment: Sorry means `if ($insert_qryy)` is another solution good work like it. Got my vote

Comment: Oh thanks. cool. you have given correct solutions too. +10 from my side.

Answer (score 1):

For checking `INSERT` query status you can use [mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) or [mysqli_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

```
$lastid = mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

**Modified example:**

```
$insert_qryy = mysqli_query($con,"Insert into user_register(name,email,phone,cphone,address,city,country,dob) 
values ('".$name."','".$email."','".$phone."','".$cphone."','".$address."','".$cityr. "','".$country."','".$dob."')") 
or die(mysqli_error()); 

$lastid = mysqli_insert_id($con);

if (intval($lastid) <= 0) 
{ 
    echo "Error"; 
}
else{
    // your second query or success.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **mysqli_affected_rows ()** function to check if data is inserted successfully into table

```
$insert_qryy = mysqli_query($con,"Insert into user_register(name,email,phone,cphone,address,city,country,dob) values('".$name."','".$email."','".$phone."','".$cphone."','".$address."','".$cityr."','".$country."','".$dob."')")or die(mysqli_error($con));

if (mysqli_affected_rows() > 0) //use this to check if data is inserted successfully into table
{   
    $handler = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `addproperty`( `purpose`, `property_type`, `city`, `title`, `description`,`property_price`, `land_area`, `expires_after`, `property_img`) VALUES  ('".$purpose."','".$type."','".$city."','".$title."','".$desc."','".$price."','".$landarea."','".$expiry."','".$im."')") or die (mysqli_error($con));
} 
else
{
    echo "something went wrong!!! at first query insertion";
}
```